# Reverse order stacked bar chart python pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I've created a stacked bar chart in python pptx with 5 series. I want to either reverse the order of the series in the bar chart (instead of S1 being on top and S4 being on bottom of the bar chart, S4 would be on top and S1 on bottom) while keeping the legend reading S1 - S4 from left to right. Or, alternatively, I could reverse the order of the legend. Any help is much appreciated!

I've tried using

> > > axis = Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
> > > axis.ReversePlotOrder

so luck so far.

Also, I've tried using "reverse_order" and no luck